# Content Porter Stuck at Expanding user selection and preparing list of items to export

Tags: web8.5, content-porter-web8

I am trying to port few keywords but the export is stuck at **Expanding user selection and preparing list of items to export**.
We have been seeing this issue from past few days. On good day it exports within normal time but on bad day it gets stuck in this step for 4 to 12 hours. Eventually it does export. The parent category of keywords I am trying to port has around thousand of keywords but either it should always have this issue or never.
At the same time if I try to port a simple component without any dependencies it gets exported. 
[image]
I have tried service host, com+ and app pool restart.

Comment: Is that scale-out CME environment? If yes, In 8.5 content porter not supported to use LB URL, it needs to use one of the box direct URL.

Comment: Can you try running the Content Porter client on the Content Manager server? Does that produce the same problem? Is there anything in the log files on the server? (I can't remember off the top of my head where the Import/Export service logs to - apologies)

Comment: Server-side logging is done to the Windows Event Log (“Tridion”).

Comment: @Velmurugan I am using the direct URL.

Comment: @JonathanWilliams No nothing in event viewer logs.

Comment: Get the CP_Export.log file from Content Porter which will give you why it's failing to expand? Go to settings ->Logging -> Enable tracing log level and try again and get the log and update the questions with log files, by default logs will generate in C:\Users\username\Documents\Content Porter\Logs

Answer (score 1):

This got resolved when we rebuild the SDL Web DB indexes.

Comment: Interesting! In general, it is worth taking a look at the DB maintenance tasks. In your case, was it a bad query plan that was causing the impact?

Comment: It was to do with large previous portings as far as we know.

Comment: You should also look to clean up the import export temp folders in the CME servers.The values are available in the Tridion.ContentManager config.